# Error: Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>'

Tags: api, flutter, dictionary, dart, dynamic

im trying to use the mediastack api but i got this error, i read about making a dynamic map but i dont know how to, any idea?

Class code

```
class Noticia {
  final String autor, titulo, descripcion, urlOrigen, fuente, imagen, categoria, lenguaje, pais, fecha;
  Noticia(this.autor, this.titulo, this.descripcion, this.urlOrigen, this.fuente, this.imagen, this.categoria, this.lenguaje, this.pais, this.fecha);
}
```

App code

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  getDatos() async{
    var response = await http.get(Uri.http('api.mediastack.com', '/v1/news?access_key=73f6b81fabc3ec26a7ec4b5dba80eb2c&keywords=salud&countries=mx&limit=3'));


    var jSonData = jsonDecode(response.body);
    List<Noticia> noticias = [];

   for(var u in jSonData){
      Noticia noticia = Noticia(u['author'], u['title'],u['description'],u['url'],
          u['source'],u['image'],u['category'],u['language'],u['country'],u['published_at']);
      noticias.add(noticia);
    }
    print(noticias.length);
    return noticias;
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(child: Text('Probar'),
        onPressed: (){getDatos();},))
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems like you're expecting `jsonDecode` to return a `List` of `Map`s, but it's probably returning only a single `Map` (or maybe a `Map` of `Map`s).  You should inspect the response (and ideally validate that the JSON response is what you expect it to be).

Comment: Please also post the api json response you are getting